# See console history on Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On DevTools console, it is possible to "preserve logs" so they don't get clear on page reload. However, in order to see a previous page logs, one has to have DevTools already open.

Is there any way to see the logs from previous visited pages in order to check for possible errors, even if DevTools wasn't open?

Thank you